# Should I include preceding 0 when using decimals in CSS?

Tags: css

Which of the following is preferred when using decimals in CSS?

padding : 0.9em;

or

padding : .9em;

Comment: Syntactically they make no difference. However, I would believe that `0.9em` is more readable.

Comment: What about loading time?

Comment: Difference in load time is insignificant.

Answer (score 3):

Whichever format you and your team have decided on as the standard to reduce complexity and increase readability.